# Error when using SUMIFS from different worksheet

Tags: excel, function, sumifs

I'm currently developing a workbook which is designed to store daily stock trading data. It has two worksheets, a main worksheet which lists each days stock trading activity, and a master sheet which is designed to show year to date, month to date and week to date trading revenue per client.

I've attached a screenshot of the master worksheet and main worksheet columns columns below:

[image: master]

[image: main sheet]

I'm trying to run a sumifs function on the master sheet which will draw data from the main data sheet. So for example if I want to know how much client A traded on a year to date basis for my master sheet I would select columns A (account name) and K (gross commission) from the data sheet as part of the sumifs function and include the client name as criteria. However, this formula continues to return a value of 0 on the master sheet which is incorrect. I've included the sumifs formula I'm using below, any help would be appreciated.

```
=SUMIFS(Maindata!A:A,Maindata!K:K,Master!A21)
```

Cell A21 refers to the location of the client name within the first column of the master worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch place for column K and A:

```
=SUMIFS(Maindata!K:K,Maindata!A:A,Master!A21)
```

[Syntax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60530&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for SUMIFS:

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

Where:

`sum_range`: range to sum (values you want to sum)

`criteria_range1`: first criteria range

`criteria1`: criteria to look/search for in your criteria range

Comment: thanks! this has worked. Would you perhaps know how to get the function to work conditionally? So that it will only collect values with certain dates (which will allow me to do it on a week to date basis etc)

Comment: Without see much of your data, you could add more criteria and match it against your date column (you can make it dynamically by use `today()` ). Open up a new question with good example and people will for sure take a look :)!!.

Comment: @NHure92 You might want to pose that as a new question.

Comment: @Wizhi I've added a date column on the data sheet now which is column A. If I wanted to do the same thing as the previous formula, while also factoring in column A and a date range of 5/09/2018 to 8/09/2018 do you possibly know how i might be able to do that? Thank you so much for the help so far

Comment: add two more criterias, something like this: =SUMIFS(Maindata!K:K,Maindata!A:A,Master!A21,Date_Column for start date, ">=Start Date",Date_Column for end date,"<=End Date")

Comment: I've tried this but it has returned an error, are there any amendments you would suggest? =SUMIFS(Maindata!L:L,Maindata!B:B,Master!A22,DATE!>=5/09/2018",DATE!<=5/09/2018")

Comment: =SUMIFS(Maindata!L:L,Maindata!B:B,Master!A22,DATE!A:A,">=5/09/2018",DATE!A:A,"<=5/09/2018")

Comment: @Wizhi thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it hasn't worked, it returns #VALUE!

Comment: whats the sheet name and column where you have your date range?

Comment: sheet name is the same as the other criteria, Maindata. Date range is listed in column A

Comment: =SUMIFS(Maindata!L:L,Maindata!B:B,Master!A22,Maindata!A:A,">=5/09/2018",Maindata!A:A,"<=5/09/2018")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183302/discussion-between-nhure92-and-wizhi).